# How convert specific number symbols to number

Tags: php

i have some string with next symbols: '１４'. How i can convert this to integer?

```
print_r((int)'１４'); // 0
```

Comment: Those are some weird numbers. You probably want to simply replace all digits with normal `0-9` digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [`mb_convert_kana`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-kana.php) to convert full-width unicode characters

```
$str = '１４';
echo (int) mb_convert_kana($str, 'n');
// 14
```